# xml cdata not allowing html

Tags: html, xml, cdata

So from what I understand of the CDATA tags on an XML document, it's meant to allow HTML tags inside it to function as they normally would.
I am working with a website template here that uses XML files, and while editing one of the documents to add a href or image to it, I rather get a string. Here's the code, if you can help me that would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried modifying the code to use the < / > that it seems to want to suggest in the output text, but that doesn't help either. If anybody can explain or link me to relevant information, or both, it would be amazing =)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xmldata section="Address">
<content>
<image src="resources/images/streetmap1.png" />

<bodytext><![CDATA[Shop 6, 106 Foster Street
     Dandenong, 3175

     Street Map:
     <image src="resources/images/streetmap1.png" />




]]></bodytext>
</content>  
    </xmldata>
```

EDIT - Supplying accompanying .js file.

http://pastebin.com/Td2EYiKH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So from what I understand of the CDATA tags on an XML document, it's meant to allow HTML tags inside it to function as they normally would.

No. It is so that characters with special meaning in XML (such as `<`) can be included *as data* without escaping.

> Here's the code

You need to look at the code that transforms the XML data into the HTML content. You haven't shared that with us.

> `<image src="resources/images/streetmap1.png" />`

The HTML element is `img` not `image` and it should have an `alt` attribute.

Comment: where would I find the code that transforms the XML data into HTML content? Sorry I'm kind of new to this, but wanted to work off the template because it looks really cool. With the template came a flash file (with actionscript in it), a javascript file and then just the other XML files.

Comment: Presumably somewhere in the JavaScript.

Comment: That just appears to load the Flash, which suggests that the Flash loads the XML, which suggests it probably isn't rendering the content as HTML.

Comment: is there some specific code that standardly renders the content as html? If so then I can at least attempt to scan through the flash file to see if I can find anything.